# Get Some Kind Of KeyStore Information from APK

Tags: android, macos, keystore

I think my KeyStore is somewhere on my Mac, but I can't seem to find where. I have already signed a previous APK with that KeyStore, but have since inconceivably lost it. I have used programs like Find Any File to no avail. Is there any way to get any kind of information about the keystore from the APK? e.g. Name, Date Created, etc....

Comment: Unzip an apk and look into the `META-INF` folder, that's all that is left from signing the apk. No info about your keystore in there.